# Powershell datagrid foreach stops after half of the rows

Tags: powershell, datagrid

I'm writing a PS-Script with UI (WinForms) which reads the open file sessions of a netapp filer via the ps modules from netapp. I want to implement a filter for the file-path of the files:

```
ForEach($markedRow in $global:dgvDataGrid.Rows){
    try{
        #write-host ($markedRow.Cells[0].value + " " + $markedRow.Cells[1].value + " " + $markedRow.Cells[2].value)
        if(!($markedRow.Cells[2].value -like '*Lync*')){
            $global:dgvDataGrid.Rows.Remove($markedRow)
        }

    } catch{
        write-host $_.Exception.Message

        }
}
```

There is a big problem with that code. It does not iterate over all Rows, it stops iterating after the half of rows. If I comment out the remove-operation, it iterates over all rows. There is no exception, I don't get it solved. May be someone of you had a similiar problem?

Answer (score 0):

Well, making the rows invisible is working, think it is better than removing.